# Handelbars complie() function returning undefined

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am compling my handelbrake file to a template and then use puppeteer to generate a pdf but the hbs.complie() function is returning undefined.

Here is the function to render the template

```
async function renderTemplate(data, templateName) {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "templates", `${templateName}.hbs`);
  if (!filePath) {
    throw new Error(`Could not find ${templateName}.hbs in generatePDF`);
  }
  console.log(filePath);
  const html = await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8");
  return hbs.compile(html)(data);
}
```

I use this function in express like this:

```
app.get("/generate-pdf", async (req, res) => {
  const htmlContent = await renderTemplate({ name: "test" }, "test");
  console.log("Content: ", htmlContent);
  await generatePDF("test.pdf", htmlContent);

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "test.pdf"));
});
```

I dont seem to know what the problem is can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

This line will always be false, because it is a string.

```js
if (!filePath) {
    throw new Error(`Could not find ${templateName}.hbs in generatePDF`);
}
```

try

```js
if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    throw new Error(`Could not find ${templateName}.hbs in generatePDF`);
 }
```

If that does not throw an error, you most likely have an undefined parameter or invalid syntax in your template.

Comment: It does not throw any error I tried your way but `htmlContent` is always undefined.

Comment: put a try catch block around the compile function, log the error to console, and check your log

Comment: no nothing in try catch I tried maybe the template is wrong?